# How to resolve 'Cannot POST /file_upload' in Nodejs application?

Tags: node.js

I was naive in Nodejs coding and can't resolve the problem further,this is file uploading program:
Here's my code:

```
    var express=require('express');
    var app=express();
    var fs=require("fs");

    var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
    var multer=require('multer');
    var jsonParser=bodyParser.json();

    app.use(express.static('public'))
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
    var upload=multer({dest:'/tmp/'});
    app.get('/index.htm',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/"+"index.htm");
    })
    app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.files.file.name);
   console.log(req.files.file.path);
   console.log(req.files.file.type);
   var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;


    fs.readFile(req.files.file.path,function(err,data){
    fs.writeFile(file,data,function(err){
    if(err){
    console.log(err);}
    else{
    response={message:'File Upload Successfully',
    filename:req.files.file.name
    };
    }
    console.log(response);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
    });
    })


    var server=app.listen(8081,function(){
    var host=server.address().address
    var port=server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s",host,port)
    })
```

However the app is running but it shows 'Cannot POST/file_upload, plz tell what to do?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {

        var storage = multer.diskStorage({

            destination: function (req, file, callback) {
                callback(null, '/tmp/');
            },
            filename: function (req, file, callback) {
                callback(null,  Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname));
            }
        });

        var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('file');

        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                res.status(200);
                res.json({

                   message:'File Upload Successfully'

                });
            }


        });

    }
```